# mod rewrite - WP

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

lately one of our clients website is under attack. Receiving ten of thousands request of non existing queries.
So, to make functions the site I declare this rule in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This kills all queries on the domain

The WP site has friendly front end links and has no queries except if user use the search of WP

The main problem is in back end. There are a lot of request of queries in /wp-admin/

So, how can I declare a rule to allow queries in backend only?

Example:

```
domain.com/some-url-name/asdasef?asdasd => deny
```

allow if wp-admin is into the url

```
wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wprocket#dashboard
wp-admin/plugin-install.php?s=cache
wp-admin/admin.php?page=mvp_settings&action=save_options
```

Thanks

Comment: Could that be a plugin of yours, making all those queries?

Comment: Hi, no. Also with all plugins off and default theme the problem persist.